# Error in my code trying get data from mqtt server to my web page Javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I have arduino esp32 which i have sent data over mqtt to my cloudmqtt broker.

What it is sending is real time random numbers.

I can view these numbers on the cloudmqtt broker but i want it to be transferred to my webpage, so i researched and found some information on websockets.

This is the code i have currently:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript MQTT WebSocket Example</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
    var host = "farmer.cloudmqtt.com"; //change this
    var port = 37511;
    var user = "foo";
    var pass = "bar";

    function MQTTconnect() {
        console.log("connecting to " + host + " " + port);
        mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client("farmer.cloudmqtt.com", 37511, "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
        //document.write("connecting to "+ host);
        var options = {
            useSSL: true,
            userName: "foo",
            password: "bar",
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: doFail
        };
        mqtt.connect(options); //connect
    };

    function onConnect() {
        // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
        console.log("Connected ");
        //mqtt.subscribe("sensor1");
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello world");
        message.destinationName = "esp/test";
        mqtt.send(message);
    }

    function doFail(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    function onMessageArrived(message) {
        console.log("onMessageArrived:" + message.payloadString);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Main Body</h1>
<script>
    MQTTconnect();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i view my conosle it doesnt seem to work and gives error:

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
webpage.html (1,1)

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: “”.
webpage.html (1,1)

connecting to farmer.cloudmqtt.com 37511
webpage.html (14,13)

0: Unspecified error.
mqttws31.min.js (28,16)

I am not sure why i get this error i dont see any errors in my code.

Comment: Assuming those are valid credentials in the code, you need change them NOW

Comment: @hardillb the port number is incorrect... and i just changed the pass